# Conver FIRTimestamp to JSON

Tags: json, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having problems converting a document to Firebase, but I can not convert the FIRTimestamp data.

```
let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: d.data(), options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (FIRTimestamp)'

Comment: Is your goal to write a field into a document with a Firestore timestamp type?

Comment: @DougStevenson Otherwise, I am trying to convert a document into a data json but when the document has a FIRTimestamp it does not leave me.

Answer (score 3):

To remove FIRTimestamp from JSON

```
 struct leadDocument: Codable {
        let state: String
        let details: String
     }
      let dataDescription = document.data() // your json response or value
      var leadData = dataDescription
      _ = leadData.removeValue(forKey: "serverTimeStamp") // remove  FIRTimestamp
     let requestData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: leadData, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) as NSData?
     let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(leadDocument.self, from: requestData! as Data)
```

OR covert  FIRTimestamp to JSON

```
 let db = Firestore.firestore()
 let settings = db.settings
 settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
 db.settings = settings
 let timestamp: Timestamp = document.get("serverTimeStamp") as! Timestamp
 let date: Date = timestamp.dateValue()
print(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to serialize the contents of a FIRTimestamp, you should either:

1. Convert it to a NSDate with [dateValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRTimestamp#-datevalue), and serialize that instead
2. Convert it to seconds (and [nanoseconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FIRTimestamp#nanoseconds) if desired) using the linked methods

When you deserialize those values, you may to convert them back into a [FIRTimestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#setdata_) with one of its constructors.

Comment: That part I understand, but how do I serialize a complete document that has a FIRTimestamp without serializing the time? that's something I think you can not do because I'm serializing the dictionary that generates the document.

Comment: Right, you have to perform the conversion I've described for the timestamp fields.

Comment: I am trying to convert the whole document into a class without having to do it field by field, I will leave a solution that I could do to my problem.

Comment: It consists in removing from the dictionary that returns the document.data() the timestamp value, then we serialize the document without the timestamp.
    public class func convert(dictionary : [String:Any]) -> Training? {

        var copy = dictionary
        let date = copy.removeValue(forKey: "trainingDate")
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: copy, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let training = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Training.self, from: json!)
        training?.trainingDate = (date as! Timestamp)
        return training
        
    }

Comment: @DougStevenson Why isn't a FIRTimestamp Codable?

Comment: @DougStevenson Seems there is working support https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseFirestoreSwift.podspec But now I need to figure it out for Carthage.